# Is there a difference between compiling for Windows 32-bit and Windows 64-bit in TMS Web Core Websites?

Tags: delphi, transpiler, target-platform, tms-web-core, pas2js

I noticed that in TMS Web Core Web Projects in Delphi, you can select `Windows 32-bit` and `Windows 64-bit` as `Target Platforms` for your website:

[image: Delphi Project Target Platforms - Windows 32-bit and Windows 64-bit]

But is there a difference between the two platforms since all we're doing is compiling Object Pascal to JavaScript?